# Resolving mass of holy disk with moment of inertia?

Tags: linear-algebra, classical-mechanics

> A uniform lamina of mass m is bounded by concentric circles with centre O and radii a and 2a. the lamina is free to rotate about a fixed smooth horizontal axis T which is tangential to the outer rim (see diagram). Show that the moment of inertia of the lamina about T is $\frac{21}4ma^2$.
>   [image]

I started with the fact that the moment of inertia of a disk through the centre of mass but not perpendicular to the surface is $\frac14mr^2$ and using parallel axis theorem I obtained the correct equation:

$$I_T = a^2(m_{2a}-\frac14m_a) + 4ma^2$$

Where m is known as $m=m_{2a}-m_a$

But I couldn't figure out how to calculate the values of $m_{2a}$ and $m_a$ in terms of $m$ to get the required answer.

Comment: The holy disk should not be confused with the sacred square nor with the saintly  triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the density of the lamina be $\rho$. Clearly $m = \pi((2a)^2 -a^2)\rho$. Thus $\rho =\frac{m}{3\pi a^2}$. Let $I_{2a}$ and $I_a$ denote the moments of inertia of circular laminas of radius $2a$ and $a$, respectively, both of which have their centres at $O$ and whose planes are parallel to $T$.

We have $I_{2a} =I_T +I_a$.

Now, $I_{2a}=\frac14\rho\pi(2a)^2(2a)^2+\rho\pi(2a)^2(2a)^2=\frac43ma^2+\frac{16}{3}ma^2$

and 
$I_a =\frac14\rho\pi a^2a^2+\rho\pi a^2(2a)^2=\frac{1}{12}ma^2+\frac43ma^2$

Finally, $I_T = I_{2a} -I_a = \frac{20}{3}ma^2-\frac{17}{12}ma^2 = \frac{21}{4}ma^2$